# Not able to get tcl script output onto the web page from the php

Tags: php, tcl

I am able to get output from the tcl script on the server ( which is huge )
But when i am calling from the the php, its not showing on the web page.
and tcl output is large and it takes 20 sec to populate on the server.
please suggest me solution as i am new to tcl and php
PHP code :

```
<?php
    echo '<pre>';
    $last_line = system('path/test',$retval);
    echo '</pre><hr />Last line of the output:' . $last_line . '<hr />
          Return value: ' . $retval;
?>
```

Comment: Where is the Tcl script being called? On the client? On the server?

Comment: I belive that you only get the last line (that contains nothing). (Tcl's `puts` adds a newline on the end.) For testing I suggest that you replace the tcl script with `cat lastoutput.txt`. If you see the same behavior, it's php that acts this way.